# Why is always threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount() <= maximumPoolSize/2?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

We have a queue of tasks and its initialising looks like:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(maximumPoolSize, maximumPoolSize, 50000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
```

The value of `maximumPoolSize` is 200. While working the queue gets a large number of threads (over a thousand), but the value returned by `threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount()` is always less than or equal to 100. For example, the value `threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount()` and `queue.size()` are logged as follows:

```
logger.debug("Active threads: " + threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount() + ".  The queue has " + queue.size() + " threads.");
```

and as a result we get the following log:

```
Active threads: 1. The queue has 0 threads.
Active threads: 2. The queue has 0 threads.
Active threads: 3. The queue has 0 threads.
Active threads: 4. The queue has 0 threads.
Active threads: 5. The queue has 0 threads.
...
Active threads: 86. The queue has 0 threads.
Active threads: 87. The queue has 1 threads.
Active threads: 88. The queue has 1 threads.
Active threads: 89. The queue has 1 threads.
Active threads: 90. The queue has 1 threads.
...
Active threads: 99. The queue has 1 threads.
Active threads: 100. The queue has 1 threads.
Active threads: 100. The queue has 2 threads.
Active threads: 100. The queue has 3 threads.
Active threads: 100. The queue has 4 threads.
...
Active threads: 100. The queue has 1874 threads.
Active threads: 100. The queue has 1875 threads.
Active threads: 100. The queue has 1876 threads.
Active threads: 100. The queue has 1877 threads.
Active threads: 100. The queue has 1878 threads.
Active threads: 100. The queue has 1879 threads.
Active threads: 100. The queue has 1880 threads.
Active threads: 100. The queue has 1881 threads.
Active threads: 100. The queue has 1882 threads.
Active threads: 100. The queue has 1883 threads.
```

The docs say that `threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount()` method

> returns the approximate number of threads that are actively executing
>   tasks

But why is the maximum threshold of this approximate value always `maximumPoolSize`/2? Is it supposed to be this way?

P.S. I couldn't reproduce this situation: on my PC I always got 200 active threads in this case. But the above logs isn't from my computer. Can it depends on the count of processors/virtual cores?

I also found the interesting piece of code in [The Grey Blog](http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com.by/2011/12/using-threadpoolexecutor-to-parallelize.html):

```
int cpus = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); 
int maxThreads = cpus * scaleFactor; 
maxThreads = (maxThreads > 0 ? maxThreads : 1);
```

But eventually I'm very confused, because the value of `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` is 8 on my PC.

Comment: Note: unless you have this many logical cpus, you might find that having more threads is slower, though it does look like you set the maximum to 100 as @VickyThakor suggests.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I edited my post

Comment: I suggest you print `threadPoolExecutor.getPoolSize()` The maximum doesn't depend on the number of cores you have, only the point at which isn't not a good idea to have more.

Comment: Add `threadPoolExecutor.getMaximumPoolSize()` to the logs - to be sure that `maximumPoolSize` is really 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that variable `maximumPoolSize` is set to `200`. It working fine at my end.

```
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SO35570728 {

    private class Task implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " started");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " finished");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(200, 200, 50000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);

        for(int i= 0 ; i < 100000 ; i++){
            System.out.println("Active threads: " + threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount() + ".  The queue has " + queue.size() + " threads.");
            threadPoolExecutor.submit(new SO35570728().new Task());
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Active threads: 0.  The queue has 0 threads.
Active threads: 1.  The queue has 0 threads.
Active threads: 2.  The queue has 0 threads.
Active threads: 3.  The queue has 0 threads.
...
pool-1-thread-1 started
pool-1-thread-2 started
pool-1-thread-3 started
...
Active threads: 200.  The queue has 99793 threads.
Active threads: 200.  The queue has 99794 threads.
Active threads: 200.  The queue has 99795 threads.
Active threads: 200.  The queue has 99796 threads.
Active threads: 200.  The queue has 99797 threads.
Active threads: 200.  The queue has 99798 threads.
Active threads: 200.  The queue has 99799 threads.
```